# Flexible chatbot uni yr1

Tags: python, chatbot

Making flexible chatbot and get error in title. How can I resolve this?

I've tried attaching str to the end.

```
end=print(random.choice("bye" or "see you" or "sayonara" or "ciao" or "arrive derci" or "goodbye" or "farewell"))
print("that was fun "+end)
```

I expect to recieve msg + msg defined by `end`, but the output is:

```
TypeError: must be str, not NoneType.
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues I see:

- `print` prints a string, but it doesn't *return* a string. Since you're setting the variable `end`, you need to remove the print part of the statement
- The `or` keyword is a logical statement, but `random.choice` takes in a collection. The part inside of the `random.choice` will currently only pick a random letter from "bye".

```py
end = random.choice(["bye", "see you", "sayonara", "ciao", "arrive derci", "goodbye", "farewell"])

print "That was fun, " + end
```